# Double induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi I'm studying Introduction to Set Theory by Hrbacek and Jech and I am not sure if I am doing a certain problem correctly. Problem 2.13 in Chapter 3 is:

(Double Induction) Let $P(x,y)$ be a property. Assume that if $P(k,l)$ holds for all $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k < m$ or ($k=m$ and $l<n$), then $P(m,n)$ holds.
Conclude that $P(m,n)$ holds for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, my interpretation of this is that
$$
(*) \,\,\,\,\forall k,l \in \mathbb{N} [k < m \vee (k=m \wedge l<n) \to P(k,l)] \to P(m,n)
$$
is true, which I'm not entirely convinced is correct. Also it seems to me that to prove something using strong induction, one must show that
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}[k < n \to P(k)] \to P(n) \,.
$$
So my proof of the double induction problem is as follows:

Consider an arbitrary $n \in\ \mathbb{N}$. Then by (*) above
$$
\forall k,l \in \mathbb{N} [k < m \to P(k,l)] \to P(m,n) \,.
$$
So by strong induction
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}[P(m,n)]
$$
and since $n$ is arbitrary
$$
\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}[P(m,n)]
$$
as desired.

Is this proof valid? The fact that the problem is titled "Double Induction" leads me to believe that I have made a mistake somewhere since I only had too use induction once. Any guidance here is appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4889767/30229). The OP's suggested approach answers your question using the second version of the induction principle on page 44 of the book. The answer by Robert Shore provides details on Brian M. Scott's alternative approach suggested in his answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The formula $\forall m\in\Bbb N[P(m,n)]$ isn’t a sentence: it has a free variable $n$. In less technical language, it doesn’t actually assert anything, so you can’t prove it.

You want to split the induction into two, one ‘inside’ the other. The outer induction is on $m$:

> Show that if $P(k,\ell)$ holds for all $k<m$ and all $\ell\in\Bbb N$, then $P(m,\ell)$ holds for all $\ell\in\Bbb N$.

Carrying out the induction step has two parts. First you have to justify the assertion that $P(m,0)$ holds. Then you have to do an induction on $\ell$ to show that $P(m,\ell)$ holds for each $\ell\in\Bbb N$.

There is, by the way, a rather different way to look at it that might be easier. Define a relation $\preceq$ on $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ by $\langle k,\ell\rangle\preceq\langle m,n\rangle$ iff either $k<m$, or $k=m$ and $\ell\le n$. Show that $\preceq$ well-orders $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$. Suppose that $B=\{\langle m,n\rangle\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N:\neg P(m,n)\}\ne\varnothing$; then $B$ has a $\preceq$-least element $\langle m,n\rangle$, from which you can derive a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see where I went wrong in my proof above and was able to prove it using double induction. Also, the secondary proof method involving the relation is pretty interesting.

Comment: @kyp4: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

First let's rewrite the problem statement more clearly:

Let $P(x,y)$ be a property, and let $A(m,n)$ denote the following statement:

---

If $P(k,l)$ holds for all $k,l∈\mathbb N$ such that either

1. $k<m$
2. $k=m$ and $l<n$

then $P(m,n)$ holds.

---

Then the problem is to prove the following:

**Proposition.** Assume that  $A(m,n)$ holds for all $m,n∈\mathbb N$. Then $P(m,n)$ holds for all $m,n∈\mathbb N$.

**Proof.** Let $Q(m,n)$ denote the property that $P(k,l)$ holds for all $k,l$ satisfying $1$ or $2$ above. We will show that $Q(m,n)$ holds for all $m,n∈\mathbb N$ by induction on $m$ (with some inductions on $n$ inside the proof).

**Base case.** $m=0$. We proceed by induction on $n$. The statement $Q(0,0)$ is vacuously true since there are no $k,l$ statisfying $1$ or $2$ in this case. Suppose $Q(0,n)$ holds for some $n \in \mathbb N$. Then, since $A(0,n)$ is true by assumption, $P(0,n)$ also holds. It follows that $Q(0,n+1)$ must hold. Therefore by the induction principle we conclude that $Q(0,n)$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

**Inductive step.** Suppose that, for some $m \in \mathbb N$, $Q(m,n)$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb N$ . We need to show that $Q(m+1,n)$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb N$. We proceed by induction on $n$ ($m$ is fixed). Since $Q(m,0)$  and $A(m,0)$ both hold by assumption, $P(m,0)$ also holds. It follows that $Q(m+1,0)$ must hold.

Now suppose $Q(m+1,n)$ holds for some $n\in\mathbb N$. There are two cases:

1. $k<m+1$ and $l\in\mathbb N$. Then either $k=m$ or $k<m$. In either case we have that $P(k,l)$ holds because $Q(m,l)$ and $A(m,l)$ both hold by assumption.
2. $k=m+1$ and $l<n+1$. Then either $l=n$ or $l<n$. In either case we have that $P(k,l)$ holds because  $Q(m+1,n)$ and $A(m+1,n)$ both hold.

It follows that $Q(m+1,n+1)$ is true. Therefore by the induction principle we conclude that $Q(m+1,n)$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

We have shown by induction on $m$ that $Q(m,n)$ holds for all $m,n∈\mathbb N$. In particular this implies that $P(m,n)$ holds for all $m,n∈\mathbb N$.